# Array.filter() and reference of objects filtered

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-filter

If we apply `array.filter` function on an array of objects, does the resultant array hold reference to the objects it filtered from the first array?

Comment: Why not just try it and find out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please don't use heading and boldface to make your entire question large and shouty. :-) Respect that the designers of the site have chosen the size and weight of fonts on purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does the resultant array hold reference to the objects it filtered from the first array

Yes, they're the same objects, `filter` doesn't clone them. It's just like doing this doesn't clone an object:

```
const a = {id: 1, value: "one"};
const b = a;
a.value = a.value.toUpperCase();
console.log(b.value); // "ONE" <== In caps
```

Live Example with `filter`:

```js
const a = [
  {id: 1, value: "one"},
  {id: 2, value: "two"},
  {id: 3, value: "three"}
];
const b = a.filter(entry => entry.id % 2);
a[0].value = a[0].value.toUpperCase();
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note that `"ONE"` is in all caps in the object, regardless of which array you get the object reference from.

Answer (score 0):

just an example that it does, check @T.J. Crowder's answer links

```js
    const arr = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:2}];

    const newArr = arr.filter(v => v.a < 3);

    newArr[0].a = 5;

    console.log(arr);
    console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: *"just an example that it doesn't"* You mean it **does**.

Comment: Aye it does appear to do so.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah yeah typo